# DataTables - sort column by image's alt strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have table with three headers. The second column consists of images. I want to implement sorting of this images using their `alt` string. I am using DataTables to help with the sorting. I have been through the documentation but still facing issues in implementing the sort. This is what I have so far

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "alt-string-pre": function(a) {
    return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
  },
  "alt-string-asc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },
  "alt-string-desc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Office</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg" width=40px alt="image1" /></td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" width=40px alt="image2" /></td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td><img src="http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121214007/destinypedia/images/7/71/Information_Icon.svg" width=40px alt="image3" /></td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have the function that can sort images using their `alt` string, but I have not been able to make it work. I am pretty new to javascript and I am not sure how to proceed here. I searched around and found we can do this using `columns` and `columnDefs` properties but haven't gotten anywhere yet. Any help/directions would be great to have. Thanks in advance.

## Edit

Updated the script.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "alt-string-pre": function(a) {
    return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
  },
  "alt-string-asc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },
  "alt-string-desc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

$('#example').dataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    type: 'alt-string',
    targets: 2
  }]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

**EDIT - 2**

Edited the code to reflect David's suggestions.

```
<script>
    jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "alt-string-pre": function ( a ) {
            return a.match(/alt="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
        },

        "alt-string-asc": function( a, b ) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "alt-string-desc": function(a,b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    } );

    $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#example').DataTable({
           columnDefs: [
           { type: 'alt-string', targets: 1 },]
          });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: There is help and example in the documentation -> **https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/alt-string**

Comment: I came across that. Thats where I got the function from. But adding the code to the `script` doesn't do anything. I have added an edit. Please cehck

Comment: If you scroll down you will see an [**EXAMPLE**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/alt-string#Example)

Comment: @davidkonrad Um actually, thats what I added to the code in the edit. Still couldn't make it work Any clue?

Comment: Yes, do not initialize the table twice :) `targets` is zerobased so you should probably use  `targets: 1` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @davidkonrad for helping out. This works now

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [HTML5 data-... attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) if you load DataTables from DOM or you can use [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html) if you load it with ajax.

Here's an example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').DataTable({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="example" width="100%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Office</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td data-sort="image1"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/new/1-freepik.jpg" width=40px alt="image1" /></td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
    <td data-sort="image2"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" width=40px alt="image2" /></td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
    <td data-sort="image3"><img src="http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131121214007/destinypedia/images/7/71/Information_Icon.svg" width=40px alt="image3" /></td>
    <td>San Francisco</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by Bogdan! Just wanted to add if you'd like to provide search capability as well as sorting, you should use the 'data-search' property with the  as follows:

```html
<td data-search="Tiger Nixon">T. Nixon</td>
```

This allows you to hide more detailed information within the table that you'd like to use for searching/sorting.